# Resetting Mikrotik RouterBoard 750GL

Tags: networking, dhcp, mikrotik-routeros

I've messed up some settings and now trying to reset this router, but the problem is, i can't. Or at least it seems i can't.

I've tried to use reset button (turning it off, holding reset button, turning it on and release reset button, the moment user led starts blinking, then waiting some time)

I've tried to use the jumper (turning it off, short circuiting it with various metal objects, turning it on and waiting some time, then releasing)
The first thing that struck me, everywhere it says that i should "wait until the configuration is cleared", but it doesn't indicate if it's doing something, instead behaves the same way as if it were simply booting up.

If i knew at least, what to expect, it would be easier, but i've done it many times and it still doesn't do anything.

What's worse, now it's dhcp server gives me an ip with subnet mask 255.255.255.255, so i can't connect to it or do anything.

Comment: The manual says: `RouterOS reset jumper hole (on the bottom of case) – resets RouterOS software to defaults. Must short circuit the metallic sides of the hole with a screwdriver and **boot the device**. Hold screwdriver in place until RouterOS configuration is cleared.` Did you boot the device while shorting?

Comment: Yes, i've short-circuited the metallic sides with a screwdriver, while holding the screwdriver in place i've turned it on. Then i've waited couple of minutes and released the jumper hole. And it says "until RouterOS configuration is cleared": How will i know if it's cleared?

Comment: I see. I have never had a device like this, can't give you a valuable advice... but did you look at Youtube videos on this matter? [This one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4SPQqvdz7yQ) shows how it is happening. Does your's behave in the same way?

Comment: sometimes this take 60-90 seconds. Try counting to 30 and if that doesn't work try counting to 60

Comment: The comment to this video that I mentioned earlier says: `Note: If you wait until LED stops flashing, and only then release the button - this will instead launch Netinstall mode, to reinstall RouterOS.`. This might be helpful.

Comment: Youtube videos have videos, but on those devices start blinking almost immediatly after you turn it off with holding the reset button. In my case it blinks one time and it happens independently of reset button being pressed.

Comment: @Yorik, i've tried to sit for whole minutes with the screwdriver on the jumper, didn't help. Still trying though)